# Milo OPC-UA Client NoSuchMethod error with io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.writeMediumLE(int)

Tags: java, maven, opc-ua, milo

I downloaded the sample code from GitHub and modified the ReadNodeExample.java just to make sure that I can connect to an OPC Server (not Milo, it's a C#-based OPC Server). I was able to verify that the sample code is able to read/write/call nodes from my server with the modifications.

I then reimplemented what I thought I needed into my actual project, but I might be missing something since I cannot connect under this project and receive the following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.writeMediumLE(int)'`

This error happens in the ClientExampleRunner.run() while running createClient()
[image]
I can still run the sample project and still connects.

Here's my pom.xml:
The org.milo is added near the end and I added what I saw was added from the sample (included ch.qos.logback and jetbrains). Then added the io.netty thinking it would help, but still have the same error.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.companyname</groupId>
    <artifactId>companyname-backend-final</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>companyname-backend-final</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>jerseyJetty</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- make the jar file -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>

                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>package org.companyname_backend_final.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>


    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!--artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.xerial</groupId> <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId> 
            <version>3.30.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.willena/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.willena</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.31.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- embedded jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- netty websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- netty http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-netty-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1.202007141445-r</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalpetri.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-channel-fsm</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.digitalpetri.fsm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>strict-machine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.70.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dictionary-reader</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
            <artifactId>server-examples</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
        <jetty.version>9.4.7.v20170914</jetty.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.28</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

My modification to the KeyStoreLoader/ClientExampleRunner. I modified the name to match my application (even in the sample) but the most notable change is that I resolve the name of the machine dynamically

```
String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
...
SelfSignedCertificateBuilder builder = new SelfSignedCertificateBuilder(keyPair)
    .setCommonName("...")
    .setOrganization("...")
    .setOrganizationalUnit("eng")
    .setLocalityName("...")
    .setStateName("...")
    .setCountryCode("...")
    .setApplicationUri("urn:" + hostName + ":OpcServer")
    .addDnsName("localhost")
    .addIpAddress("127.0.0.1");
```

In the ClientExample, I only changed the EndpointUrl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your actual project has an old version of Netty somewhere on its classpath.

`ByteBuf::writeMediumLE` (and all the other `LE`-suffixed `ByteBuf` methods) were introduced in Netty 4.1.

Comment: Thanks for direction! Just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I left out. I noticed nothing in the .classpath but after some digging, saw the 4.0.25 version of the jar files somewhere but can't track down which dependency was using that older version. I'll see if I can upgrade the jar though.

Comment: After some SO digging, ran `mvn dependency:tree` to find the dependency and it was this https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio - updated to 1.7.18 (previously 1.7.7) and now able to communicate! Now to check if it broke something else... but at least I can continue with this step. Thanks!